# How do I use 2 loops, and if it is false, repeat the program indefinetely

Tags: python, loops

Right now I am doing the tutorial "Dragon Realm" from this site http://inventwithpython.com/chapter6.html

I understand what it's all doing slightly but that is not my problem. At the end I'm wanting to add a bit of code that if the player says no, it says, as I currently have it, "too bad *******!" and move back up to the beginning of the program. I've gotten it to do that, but once it goes through the second time and i get to the input of whether you want to try again whether or not you type yes or no it just ends the program. I've tried multiple combinations of while, if/else, while True, while False and I am not getting the results I am wanting. I don't understand how you just keep it to keep going? It's probably really simple but I can't figure it out.

this is the code for the program.

```
import random
import time
def displayIntro():
    print('You are in a land full of dragons. In front of you,')
    print('you see two caves. In one cave, the dragon is friendly')
    print('and will share his treasure with you. The other dragon')
    print('is greedy and hungry, and will eat you on sight.')
    print()
def chooseCave():
    cave = ''
    while cave != '1' and cave != '2':
        print('Which cave will you go into? (1 or 2)')
        cave = input()
    return cave
def checkCave(chosenCave):
    print('You approach the cave...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('It is dark and spooky...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('A large dragon jumps out in front of you! He opens his jaws and...')
    print()
    time.sleep(2)
    friendlyCave = random.randint(1, 2)
    if chosenCave == str(friendlyCave):
        print('Gives you his treasure!')
    else:
        print('Gobbles you down in one bite!')
playAgain = 'yes'
while playAgain == 'yes' or playAgain == 'y':
    displayIntro()
    caveNumber = chooseCave()
    checkCave(caveNumber)
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    playAgain = input()
```

Comment: no need for foul language

Comment: Please reduce the code to the essential part of your problem.

Comment: Excuse me for posting what I had in my code, but noted, although your censorship offends me more.

Comment: Andre the issue has been resolved but, thanks for your interest in helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add simply,

```
if 'n' in playAgain:
    print "too bad"
    playAgain = 'yes'
```

At the end (inside your while loop)

By the way, these two lines can be combined:

```
print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
playAgain = input()
```

as simply:

```
playAgain = input('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
```

Because `input` will display the string argument when asking for input.